# VB.net VS2013 office.interop.excel suddenly not found?

Tags: vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2013, reference

I loaded up a current application project to implement some updates to the code and all of a sudden my program won't compile.

I've already got versions of this program in use which work just fine.

The issue seems to be with the Microsoft office object library. I have checked my references and it is shown as checked.

[image]

Yet VS2013 now cannot find the library. I have removed and re-added the library with no effect.

No other libraries seem to be affected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Microsoft. Excel Library or something similar search excel into .net framework references

Comment: If you click the library, in the properties window, does it say `Resolved`= 'True'?

Comment: @DrDonut - yes it does say Resolved = True

Comment: Errata Corrige: `Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library` in `COM` references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

I added the DLL files for interop.excel and interop.outlook manually by going to properties --> References --> add --> Browse --> locate the dll library.

I used [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) to figure out where they were and this worked.

Thanks to all who offered help!